# Grails: 'size' attribute is not working for <gui:autoComplete>

Tags: grails

My question is regarding the autoComplete tag of grails-ui plugin. The size attribute to limit the size of the field is not working for the grails-ui autoComplete tag. Is it supposed to work or is the attribute not added to the taglib of autoComplete?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-grails-ui/trunk/grails-app/taglib/org/grails/grailsui/InputTagLib.groovy and check the method 'def autoComplete' your are going to see that there is no Size attribute, for that tag!